# How can I exit fullscreen (created by using fullscreen api) by scrolling my mouse or, if that is not possible by left click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Entirely using JavaScript with jQuery, I'm doing a university project and the requirements are somewhat strict. I'm using full-screen for my image gallery. I'm kind of stumbling in the dark here because it's my first time writing code in JavaScript, let alone writing it for a web site, I've tried to utilize `eventListener`, attempting to adapt a piece of code from here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API
but that clearly isn't the right method. I want to make my utilization of the API a tad fancier since I went the path of least resistance with picking it. This is my attempt at writing the code, for whatever that's worth.

```
function toggleFullscreen() {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
    document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have demonstrated an approach below.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/huzi8t9/pen/VwgbNYN)

```js
const toggleFullScreen = () => {
  if(!document.fullscreenElement) {
    document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
    return true
  }
  else {
    document.exitFullscreen();
    return false
  }
}

const handleScroll = e => {
  toggleFullScreen();
}

const toggleLink = document.querySelector('.toggle')
const el = document.querySelector('.element')

document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', e => {
  if(!document.fullscreenElement) {
    el.removeEventListener('scroll', null)
  }
})

toggleLink.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const fullscreen = toggleFullScreen();
  
  if(fullscreen) {
    el.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
  }
})
```